# google-api-java-client: setForMine(true) causes invalidSearchFilter error

Tags: java, youtube, google-api-java-client

If I call

```
YouTube.Search.List.setForMine(true);
```

then I get the following error even though `YouTube.Search.List.setType("video")` is also called as required by the use of `YouTube.Search.List.setForMine(true)`:

```
There was a service error: 400 : Invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions.
hu.pocketguide.kmlvideo.youtube.exception.YouTubeException: Service error.
    at com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.data.PgFindByKmlId.findVideosByKmlId(PgFindByKmlId.java:107)
    at com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.data.PgFindByKmlId.main(PgFindByKmlId.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "youtube.search",
    "location" : "",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message" : "Invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions.",
    "reason" : "invalidSearchFilter"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions."
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1049)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.data.PgFindByKmlId.findVideosByKmlId(PgFindByKmlId.java:100)
    ... 7 more
```

The same query in the Try it! section of https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list works.

Can anyone tell me how to list my own "unlisted" videos using google-api-java-client filtering for tags (keywords)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I failed to pass an appropriate Credential object to `new YouTube.Builder(...)`. With the following initialization it works:

```
List<String> scopes = Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly");
Credential credential = Auth.authorize(scopes, "mycredentialdatastore");
            youtube = new YouTube.Builder(
                    Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT,
                    Auth.JSON_FACTORY,
                    credential).setApplicationName("mysample").build();
```

Still, I find the error message misleading.

Comment: Were you able to add filter for tags in your search query? If yes, what was your query parameter syntax?